# difference between By and Through- "Through the use of" vs "By the use of"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> Through the use of scientific method it has been demonstrated that unsanitary conditions cause the spread of diseases.

Why the writer could not use ***By*** instead of ***Through***?

Comment: You may want to check this: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25459/what-general-rules-govern-the-usage-of-by-versus-through

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the writer could have used any of the following:

1. By means of scientific method...
2. By applying scientific method...
3. By using scientific method...
4. By way of using scientific method...

But **"through"** implies a action that has a start point and an end point which means that the scientific method helped all the way through and wasn't just a means, a resource or an instrument.